# $x+\frac{1}{y}=y+\frac{1}{z}=z+\frac{1}{w}=w+\frac{1}{x}=t$, find $t$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

> $x, y, z,$ and $w$ are distinct real numbers and $t$ is a positive real number such that $x+\frac{1}{y}=y+\frac{1}{z}=z+\frac{1}{w}=w+\frac{1}{x}=t$, find $t$.

As $y=t-\frac{1}{z}$, by substituting in $t-\frac{1}{z}$ for $y$, $x+\frac{1}{t-\frac{1}{z}}=t$. Thus, $x+\frac{1}{t-\frac{1}{t-\frac{1}{t-\frac{1}{x}}}}=t$, which simplifies to $\frac{t^3x-t^3-xt-3t+1}{t^2x-t-x}=t$. (I'm not sure if my expansion is wrong.)
However, I cannot solve this equation. Can anyone solve it?

Comment: If the final equation is correct then it is equivalent to the cubic$$t^3-t^2+3t-1=0$$which has a single positive real solution given by$$t=\frac13 \left(1 - \frac8{\sqrt[3]{1 + 3 \sqrt{57}}} + \sqrt[3]{1 + 3 \sqrt{57}}\right)$$

Comment: However I don't know if the final equation is even correct.

Comment: @xrider1000: Your final equation is not correct. I checked it: $(t^3-2t)x^2-(t^4-2t^2)x+t^3-2t=0$

Comment: and that last equation factors as $ t \left(t^2-2\right) \left(x^2-t x+1\right)=0$

Comment: so does that mean $t=\sqrt 2$?